# Blocking Hotspotshiled?

Tags: proxy, vpn, iptables, squid

I am responsible to monitor my university network and recently I have noticed which students are using a VPN called as "hotspotshield" that pass my proxy server and allow them to browse and use any website or ports, even the ports that are already blocked, I just want to know if there is any option to block this hotspotshield using iptables, squid or something similiar?

Answer (score 3):

Based on this forum discussion - http://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1531 - it appears that you have to connect to box.anchorfree.net in order for hotspotshield to work. It resolves as follows -

box.anchorfree.net. 78161   IN  A   74.115.0.34
box.anchorfree.net. 78161   IN  A   74.115.0.35

Therefore, how about trying to block any access from your network to those IP addresses?

iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d 74.115.0.34 -j DROP

or maybe use REJECT instead of DROP.

Disc: I haven't had time to install the hotspot software to test this.